# Destroy User not working on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using devise on my Users controller right now and can't seem to destroy my users. Edit, new still work. Destroy only redirects me to showing the user attributes.

My User Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def new
    @user = User.new
end

def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
    redirect_to users_path
    else
    render 'new'
    end
end

  def index
    @users=User.all
  end

def edit
@user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy
    redirect_to users_path
end

def delete

end

def update
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
  redirect_to user_path(@user.id)
 else
  render 'edit'
 end
end

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

private

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password)
    end

end
```

User View:

```
<h1>Users#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/users/index.html.erb</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>email</td>
        <td>password</td>
    </tr>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= link_to user.name, user_path(user.id) %></td>
        <td><%= user.email %></td>
        <td><%= user.password %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "edit user", edit_user_path(user.id) %> </td>
        <td><%= link_to "destroy user", user, method: :delete %> </td>
    </tr>


    <% end %>

</table>
```

Does it have something to do with the

```
<td><%= link_to "destroy user", user, method: :delete %> </td>
```

line? It seems like this is the line that is giving me the most trouble. I am using devise if that is relevant, and I am also having issues trying to get it fixed.

My rake routes:

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                   posts GET    /posts(.:format)               posts#index
                         POST   /posts(.:format)               posts#create
                new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)           posts#new
               edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)      posts#edit
                    post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#show
                         PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#update
                         PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#update
                         DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#destroy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)               users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)               users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)           users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
                         PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)           users#destroy
```

Comment: Just remove your method delete from controller

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using devise, it wont work in your regular controller.

You would have to use the registration path not the user path:

```
<%= link_to "Delete User", registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete %>
```